# How can I force VS2010 to stop using an outdated plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, tfs, telerik, msscci

When I close a Telerik "RadControlsWebsite" project in VS2010, I get, "*This plugin is intended for older versions of Visual Studio. Please use Team Explorer.*"

Then, when I dismiss that dialog, I see, "*There was a failure while initializing the Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider source control provider. You cannot use this provider to perform source control operations.*"

Although I do have TFS, I didn't bind this project to it. So what outdated plugin is it trying to use, why is it trying to use it, and how can I circumvent future "so we meet again"s with this rascally rarebit?

### UPDATE

I see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/4775882e-2675-4f6f-ba6f-6c67d2e7dcd0 a hint on what to do, but at the location specified by GiangShi (in my case it's VS 10.0 | CurrentSourceControlProvider), I only see this key:

```
Name=Default
Type=REG_SZ
Data={googledyboobopetc}
```

If I'm using TFS, do I need to change this val, or add a new val, or what (to use TFS, but get rid of the err msg)?

Comment: Did you try set `Plug-in Selection` to `None` and then back to `Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` as suggested in the link?

Comment: How old is your version of RadControls? Will the company spring for the updated software package?