# How can I get TFS working again?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msscci

Today I checked out a new project in TFS (Visual Studio 2010): [Which, if any, folders do I need to create before checking out a TFS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386858/which-if-any-folders-do-i-need-to-create-before-checking-out-a-tfs-project)

The .sln file wouldn't save (said it was read-only, and even when changing that in Windows Explorer, it made no difference).

So, I created a new folder, created a new .sln, and then copied all the other files over to that structure.

Now, somehow, TFS has "given up the ghost" On connecting (I do seem to connect, I can see the projects in the Team Explorer pane), when I 2-click the "Source Control" item below a project, I get, "*Team Foundation Server is not your current Source Control plug-in. Click here to set the current Source Control plug-in.*"

If I do fall for its ploy, I then see, "*Error Command "Tools.Options" does not accept arguments or switches.*"

What in blue blazes is going on?!?

I reinstalled ("repaired", as that was the only option other than uninstall) MSSCCIProvider, but that did no good - I get the same errors. How can I get TFS back?

### UPDATE

I *am* connecting to TFS, because when I open VS and select the "Connect to TFS" (verbiage?) link, it opens the Team Explorer tab, with a visual representation of the TFS server, with the various "areas" below that, and then, for the area I'm currently working on:

```
Handheld
    > Work Items
    Reports
    > Builds
    Source Control
```

...but when I mash "Source Control," it tells me, "TFS is not your current Source Control plug-in. Click here to set the current Source Control plug-in."

But that's a bait-and-switch, because when I do (click there), I get the err msg, "Error< crlf > Command "Tools.Options" does not accept arguments or switches."

Comment: I created the folder so that I could actually have a project - the .sln file would not save and thus the one TFS created was useless to me as it was; without a solution file, the .vb files were simply a gaggle of orphans. As Jim said, it was "rackety times in the nussery."

Comment: Maybe this thread which is about VS2008 might help. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4775882e-2675-4f6f-ba6f-6c67d2e7dcd0/problem-with-vs-2008-team-foundation-server-msscci-provider
1) Open VS2008
2) In "Options" -> "Source Control" -> "Plug-In Selection" select "None"
3) Close VS2008
4) Open VS2008
5) In "Options" -> "Source Control" -> "Plug-In Selection" select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server"
6) Close VS2008

Comment: you're using VS 2010 but you've tagged MSSCCI, which you shouldn't be using that with 2010. MSSCCI is for older version of VS (2003) and non MS tools. What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Please make your TFS version explicit by applyign the versioned tag to your question. Which version of TFS are you trying to connect to? Also check out my blog posts on how to connect to TFS 2012 or the Team Foundation Service from an older client: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/search/label/Connect-To-TFS

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Options? In VS 2010, I see no such menu item; there is Project > HDP Properties > but no "Options" there, or "Source Control" that I've found yet...

Comment: @JamesReed: I don't know what version of TFS it is, nor do I see how to determine that. I've got the "Team" top-level menu item, but no "About" type item to give me that info. Yes, I think that perhaps the solution would be to tell it not to try to use MSSCCI, but I don't know how to tell it that. Dijkgraaf's comment seems good, but I see  no "Options" menu...

Comment: In visual studio you will have a "tools" menu. Select "options" and then select "Source Control". Make sure that the "Current source control plug-in" is set to "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" You should then be able to use "Team Explorer" to manage your code in TFS.

Comment: @jessehouwing: please see my update in response.

Comment: @JamesReed: Ah, that did it. It was, as expected, set to MSSCCI, and I switched it to TFS.

Comment: @JamesReed: If you make that (your last comment) an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my comment, it looks like you have the wrong source control plugin enabled in Visual Studio. In visual studio go to "Tools", "Options", "Source Control"

Make sure that the "Current source control plug-in" is set to "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server"

You should now be able to use Team Explorer to manage your code in TFS